# VBA Workbook.Open Run-time error '91'

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling, maximize-window

I want an Event-handling macros that maximizes the excel workbook and window on opening.  I want this as  a personal macro that would work on any of my workbooks.  I currently have this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
   ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

It is saved the "VBAProject (PERSONAL.XLSB)" within "ThisWorkBook"

The code maximizes the workbook, but it gives me the Run-time error '91' when it reaches "ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized".  Can anyone help me with this?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your code is assuming that there's an `ActiveWindow`, which isn't guaranteed.

Use `If Not [object] Is Nothing Then...` to check if an object reference is usable:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
   If Not ActiveWindow Is Nothing Then ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  What workbook event would then maximize the ActiveWindow once it is available?  I have tried Workbook_Activate, Sheets_Activate, but the window does not maximize.